# how to use curvature in paint mode?

Tags: texture-painting

i'm trying to use curvature while painting texture, but it seems to fail in some way.

[image]

dirty vertex color seems fail too

[image]

i just modeled this object in one minute in freshly opened blender. what am i supposed to do to make right curvature calculations?

more simplier shape just appears to have no cavity at all.

[image]

i'm using blender 2.76b btw

EDIT:
just tested it with deformed plane and it worked!!!

[image]

but how am i supposed to paint over complex mesh?

Answer (score 3):

come to a solution based on the fact that cavity is calculated in blender based on the verticies. made a tripple subdivisio and was able to paint edges properly.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to generate a curvature map by baking the mesh's curvature then add a layer and paint in overlay mode.